# Custom URL Schemes on iphone oauth twitter

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, twitter-oauth, url-scheme

After sending the user to safari to authorize, i get sent to
mobile.twitter.com as opposed to my custom url scheme (something like
myapp://). at the request token step, I did receive
oauth_callback_confirmed=true.

I've tried using a normal link like http://www.teamliquid.net, which
works fine. Is there something I am missing?

I've also tried directly typing "myapp://" into safari and it correctly redirects me back into my application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question.

`myapp://` is not to spec. You must add a path. something like `myapp://oauth`, or simply use `myapp:` (without slashes)

also, you must implement the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`
method in your app delegate. there you will receive your `myapp://oauth?oauth_token=xxx&oauth_verifier=yyy` so you may begin your access token step.