# What should the Request URI be when creating an oAuth 2.0 server implementation?

Tags: oauth-2.0

After reading through the [oAuth 2.0 draft 23](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23) I have a better understanding of how oAuth works, however one thing I'm not understanding is the request uri:

I've read the section in the draft and it explains the request uri needs to be an absolute url from the client but if I am making an android/iphone app then what must this value be as my app is not a website on a web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own custom URI scheme, say

```
myapp://oauthcallback
```

Now you setup your app to listen for this scheme (works on [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958701/1467115) and on [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5384467/1467115)). When your browser/webview then gets redirected after the authorization request, your app will start and you can handle the query parameters sent with the URI.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the explanation and links to Android and iOS implementation examples :)